# How to resize jQuery carousel with CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically I have a jQuery image carousel that is the full width of the browser and everything looks good on my computer (resolution 1980x1020). But, on smaller resolutions the carousel/images doesn't resize at all, so it looks horrible. I would post screenshots to make it 10x easier to explain but I literally just made my account to ask this question and don't have enough 'reputation' to post images.

Basically every element on the page re-sizes accordingly because it sits inside a wrapper that is set to `width: 100%`, and then the element itself has a min-width of `1100px` and `margin: 0 auto` so when the browser is resized, it stays centered. The image carousel is styled differently of course because both the carousel ul and the images have to be width: 100%, so I'm unsure how to go about this?

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Set the interval to be 5 seconds
    var imgWidth = $(".imgCar").width();
    var t = setInterval(function () {
        $("#carousel ul").animate({ marginLeft: -imgWidth }, imgWidth, function () {
            $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
            $(this).css({ marginLeft: 0 });
        })
    }, 10000);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="carousel">
    <ul>
        <li><img class="imgCar" src="/images/homepage carousel/pic1.jpg" /><div><h1>BRAND NEW OFFICES FOR SALE IN GLASGOW</h1><p>Over 200 offices for sale in Glasgow</p><a href="#">More Info</a></div></li>
        <li><img class="imgCar" src="/images/homepage carousel/pic2.jpg" /><div><h1>HEAD OFFICE REFURB COMPLETE</h1><p>The refurbishment of our head office is complete</p><a href="#">Take a look</a></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#carousel {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 600px;
}

#carousel ul {
    width: 3960px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 600px;
}

#carousel ul li {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    float:  left;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: provide code. You can embed a working snippet to question as well

Comment: @hjpotter92 Done mate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to attach a function on window resize

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
         //Resize your carousel based on the window size
 });
```

Comment: Hi Vasil.

I should probably have stated this in the question but my main concern isn't with the resizing of the browser but more about how this will look on smaller screen? I have a fairly large desktop monitor so the carousel looks fine, but I'm not sure how it will look on, say, iPhones? window resize would work well with browser changes but what I really want to do is make sure the image carousel looks good on all sizes of screens? Sorry for not specifying that in my original question.

Comment: If the concern is how everything it will looks like on smaller devices try some browser extensions that will show you how everything will be in smaller resolution devices. I do not want to tell which one you have to use (I don't want to say product names), but every one of these extensions works on the same way. I hope that I understood your concern correct and I hope that I helped.